# Rails -- routing: using a sub-directory before controller/action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Say I have an application called employeesmanager, and it has an `employees` resource, so `/employees/new` is a new employee etc.  I want to have the name of the company preceding this action, so for example, `ford/employees/new` should create a new employee at ford, while `exxon/employees/new` should create a new employee at exxon.  What is the best way to do this?

Ideally I don't want to have to use nested controllers with `/company/exxon/employees/new` because that seems like extra wasted words in the URL that can be annoying to type in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scope ":company_name" do
  resources :employees
end
```

For more details check out [Rails Guides on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers).

Comment: Also you can restrict which parameters matches this query via adding `:constraints => {:company_name => /[a-z\d_\-]+/i }` regexp to `scope` call. Beware of route ordering.

Comment: I don't think you need the quotes around ":company_name"

Comment: This is a path segment (string) just like "companies/:company_name/employees". It is not related to ruby symbols aside looking similar. Try it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

You can try smth like that:

```
get "/:company/employees/new" => "employees#new"
```

In that case request with `GET` method to this path will be passed to `EmployeesController#new` and in `params[:company]` it'll receive company name.

Comment: is there a convenient way to do this so I don't have to do that setup with every single path and can still use `resource :employees`?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to prepend that dynamic company name in front of default RESTful routes generated by `resource :employees`.